# As a graduate, is creating a log-in in the university online campus considered an acceptance of their offer?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Is creating a log-in in the university online campus considered an acceptance of their offer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For any normal and reputable University, no - logging into an online system is not a "got you now, sucker!" moment.

The only way to accept an offer is to formally respond to your offer of admission to the graduate coordinator or graduate school, usually in the form of a signed document - or otherwise unequivocally answering "yes" in a digital form, such as an e-signature.

Comment: It is worth noting that in the rules you (usually) have to accept when creating account there may be a note that you are not supposed to create account if you do not accept offer or something like that. If that's the case, creating account is not an acceptance, of course, but it is minor misconduct.

Comment: @Mołot in those cases I'd expect the account creation to be done for you on acceptance, the credentials being presented to you on your first day there. Which is how many if not most companies handle handing accounts to new employees.

Comment: @jwenting in theory, you are right. In practice? Reading site rules before clicking "I accept" is the only way to be sure, and that's what I wanted to remind. Best practices are more often ignored in academia setting than in a workplace one, from my experience.

Comment: @Mołot of course, always read the small print.